# Where can I get some uranium?

Tags: kittens-game

I've reached the point where I need lots of uranium to build space bases and get unobtanium, but it (the uranium) seems to be pretty difficult to produce.

Each accelerator gives me 0.03/sec, but each lunar outpost, for example, requires 1.75/sec to run. That means I'll need 60 accelerators *per lunar base*? I'm only at 5 and it already takes me all day to produce enough titanium for 1 more.

Am I missing something?

Comment: do you have any paragon?

Comment: yes, 20 at the moment. should I reset a couple more times to build up paragon before trying for space?

Comment: I hope this makes it to the trending page!

Comment: @LarsEbert it did.

Comment: [From Amazon.com](http://smile.amazon.com/uranium-unrefined-uraninite-radiation-detector/dp/B00CQ9LLR4/), apparently.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

While having a greater amount of paragon would be helpful (although not as much as you would expect), in order to substantially boost your accelerator output you need to build both Magneto's & Steamworks. The more of each of these you have the higher your resource production will be.

Another thing which can boost your output is the religion upgrade

**Solar Revolution** - Accumulated faith will give a small boost to resource production

The higher your accumulated faith the greater the boost to production.

Please note that these will impact not only your Uranium production but also any other resource production

Comment: somehow i didn't even notice that the tooltip for my accelerator output was already including the buffs from magnetos/steamworks. I guess i'll just stock up on those :)

Answer (score 6):

I do not know of previous game versions but as of today, each "Planet Cracker" on Dune can give you 1.50/sec.

I guess this would not exist the moment this question was asked, but it is useful for people coming back here from google.

Of course everything noted on the accepted answer is still correct as well.

Answer (score 2):

I trade with Dragons for uranium. Then, just make sure the automated income isn't too far in the negative, and when you sit down to play you can make a couple of hundred trades.